# How to write attribute without value in JSF?

Tags: angularjs, jakarta-ee, jsf-2, angular-ui, angular-ui-router

I am developing AngularJS application in JSF 2. Since, my files are in XHTML format, the following syntax are not accepted:

```
<div ui-view/>
```

The compiler complains that `ui-view` should have a value assigned to. However, it seems AngularJS treat differently if `ui-view` is assigned with value.

In fact, `ui-view` is just one example. There are some other cases where attribute values are not expected by angularJS.

How to code this in JSF? I guess I should switch to HTML5, instead of XHTML? How to do so?

Answer (score 0):

Try like this

```js
<div ui-view=""/>
```